# Define variable with route parameter. But keep it undefined if parameter is not found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I have an Angular 7 component where I am getting a route parameter value:

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  postId: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.postId);

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(parameters => {
      this.postId = +parameters.get('postId');
    })

    console.log(this.postId);

  }

}
```

In the first Console Log `postId` is undefined as expected.

On the second Console Log `postId` is 0 as `postId` is not found in the URL.

I would like `postId` to stay undefined if `postId` is not found in the URL.

How could I do that?

Comment: Why is it 0? Where do you set it to that value?

Comment: Yes, `+null` is 0. Test if the parameter is truthy before transforming it to a number and assigning it to your field.

Comment: @JBNizet Is there a short way to do that?

Comment: `const postIdParam = parameters.get('postId'); if (postIdParam) { this.postId = +postIdParam; }`

Comment: I tried the following working code: parameters.get('postId') ? +parameters.get('postId') : undefined; ... I was wondering if there was a shortest way but it seems it work this way.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-detail',
  templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-detail.component.css']
})
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const postId = params['postId'];
      const postIdToUse = postId ? +postId : undefined;
      console.log('Got the PostId as :' , postIdToUse);
    });
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/optional-undefined-if-param-not-present?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: @Chris, it's ideally suggested that if we assign a "*not defined*" value to a variable, we do that using `null`. That lets us differentiate between a value that was declared but not initialized vs something that we actually set ourselves.